# How to write to console of subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, console, subprocess

I'm trying to write to a subprocesse's command line. The application is in an .exe file and doesn't support arguments when it is run I've tried.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("c:\users\user\downloads\Application")
p.communicate("000")
p.communicate("#\n")
```

How can I input to the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the Popen.commuincate() docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

It clearly states that you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE to send data to the process's stdin.

so

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen("c:\users\user\downloads\Application", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("000")
p.communicate("#\n")
```

Comment: It throws an error: "NameError: name PIPE is not defined" at line 2

Comment: @user1461837 I have updated the answer now. Please check.

Comment: How do I get the output of stdout from the file? I tried adding stdout=PIPE argument to no avail.

Comment: @user1461837: `.communicate()` waits for the child process to finish and therefore you may call it at most once. Pass all the input at once: `p.communicate(input=os.linesep.join(["000", "#" + os.linesep]).encode())`